# Can i access objects cached in server from Windows service?

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

I'm caching some objects in code behind in web page
i want to implement a windows service that keep refreshing this object with latest data
can i access the System.web.caching from windows service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some kind of web service using a generic handler and have the Windows service talk to that to update items on the web site.

However, personally I'd use an external cache like Couchbase (Memcache) and have both the web site and the Windows service use that instead.

Comment: i have created a web service but i still cannot access the system.web.caching.cache static object inside the webmethod , this object is only accessible if page inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Comment: You can use `HttpRuntime.Cache` or `HttpContext.Current.Cache`.

Comment: thank you :) i have another question, i noticed that the object i store in cache removed after some time , how can i configure this to make it stay longer? i tried when i insert it to cach to provide expiration date after a month, but its gone. i notice that the memory of the server is very low , maybe it become full and data lost from cache? or its configuration issue?

Comment: Caching will use the time yes but it will also clean up older entries when memory becomes scarce and/or other factors are fulfilled. It's not meant for long term storage it's meant for fast access and you should always allow for fallback.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the ASP.net cache as a shared cache between the Windows Service and the Web Site. The Windows Service will not be able to access this.

In order to do what you want, you should use an external cache. For example, set up [Redis](http://redis.io/) on the same machine or on a different accessible machine, and access it from the the Windows Service to refresh your data, and from the Web Site to retrieve the pre-cached data.

Comment: You CAN use the cache assuming you can provide a way to read into and out of it externally (like a web service).

Comment: @Lloyd yes, you can. But his question was about using it from a Windows Service.

Comment: And my point still stands. Expose the cache within the web site to the Windows service by providing an interface to it (aka a web service or somesuch).